# Bootstrap Tab going out of screen width

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I have tried using class row over this div but could not shift tabs in next line..

```
 <div class="navwrap">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
            <li class="nav-item" *ngFor="let menu of menudata; let i=index">
                <a class="nav-link" (click)="changecategory(i,menu.id)" [class.active]="menu.isSelected" data-toggle="tab" role="tab">{{menu.name}}</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

How to shift remaining tags in other line?

[Current Image tabs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kYv1w.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add 'flex-wrap' Class with nav, So you can move tab in new line

```
<div class="navwrap">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs flex-wrap" role="tablist">
            <li class="nav-item" *ngFor="let menu of menudata; let i=index">
                <a class="nav-link" (click)="changecategory(i,menu.id)" [class.active]="menu.isSelected" data-toggle="tab" role="tab">{{menu.name}}</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) 
Using flexbox you can fix your rows or columns either having fixed dimensions, content-sized dimensions or remaining-space dimensions.